# Скачать файл и положить его в download

Tags: android, файлы, файловая-система, download

**Исходное**: на мобилке(Android) генериться текстовый файл (CSV)

**Цель**: пользователь нажимает на кнопку и сгенерированный файл предлагается скачать. Пользователь соглашается и файл падает в Download или другая доступная директория, вообщем куда-то где пользователь сможет зайти. Потом этот файл пользователь например может переслать по почте как вложение (в почтовой программе есть возможность его найти, например в директории Download)

**Вопрос**: как сделать это? предполагаю что это делается через Intent и WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, только не могу понять как

Comment: Не совсем ясно: *"на мобилке генерится текстовый файл"* и *"пользователь нажимает на кнопку, и сгенерированный файл предлагается скачать"*. Откуда вы хотите скачать файл, если он генерируется на самом устройстве? "Скачивание" подразумевает сетевой запрос на какой-то сервер. [Уточните](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1502462/edit) ваш вопрос.

Comment: Смотрите ContentResolver метод insert